# Is there a performance difference when if "http" is appended on CDN calls?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating a local static site and appended CDN script links for jQuery and Bootstrap.

I noticed that it wouldn't connect and had to add the `http:` prefix in the src attribute (which I think is needed locally).  Is there a performance difference once I have the site live in production and the prefix is left?

Comment: Without the protocol, the URI is *protocol relative*. This means it will use the same protocol as the page itself.

Comment: Instead of adding `http:` while developing locally I just spin up a simple web-server (in OSX this is really easy: http://www.andyjamesdavies.com/javascript/simple-http-server-on-mac-os-x-in-seconds) this also lets you use web server conventions in terms of resource paths

Comment: I hate when an API only puts `//` in its resource loader (Google+ I'm talking about you) and causing the things to break and I have to patch it myself.

Comment: @JasonSperske, That is an awesome solution!  Any chance you could make this to a "full response" below, so I could select it as the answer?

Comment: Thanks! I added it to Brandt's answer as it covers the more general "why". Glad I could help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will only matter if `https` is involved with the page, as anything with `http` will flag a security warning. Since you are requesting an external file from another server, the protocol moniker is required (as you experienced)

To make the request protocol agnostic, do something like:

```
<script ..... src="//cdn.domain.com/file.ext" >
```

The cleanest solution is to run a local web server (allowing you to leverage HTTP resource conventions and protocol agnostic resources). On OSX you can start up a simple http server with the following commands

```
> cd /path/to/project/folder
> python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080
```

Answer (score 2):

If an absolute URL in a link or script starts with `//`, it means that it should use the same protocol as the current page.

If you specify the *http* (or *https*) protocol, you are forcing the browser to retrieve that resource using that protocol.

If a page is downloaded using a secure connection and there is a JS or CSS resource in the page that wants be downloaded as normal *http*, then most browsers will generate a security warning. So having the URL omit the protocol and start with `//` will have the benefit that it will be fast on an http page (as *http* is faster than *https*), and will still be secure on an https page (so no browser warning).

The problem with this is that if you use a protocol different from http or https (most notably the protocol for local file system `file:`, i.e. when you open an HTML file in your hard disk), then it will be unable to locate the resource because, using the same protocol as the main page, it will try to find the resource in your local file system, which most likely does not contain it, resulting in an error.